# How to stop Navigation bar Background Image stop repeating?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have got following code to display Image for background of a Navigation bar:

```
UIImage *imgNav = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:imgNav forBarMetrics:
 UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The image size is 60 by 42. Now I just want single instance of a image but it repeats. How to disable it? I want the single instance of a image at centre of navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think no body understood my problem my bad. ! I should have posted this image earlier.

But I solved it myself. This wont happen if you make the image exactly 320 by 44 pixel because that's the size  of the navbar.

OR if you just want to set Title Image at the center of the screen it should be implemented this way in a view Controller:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = 
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_logo.png"]];
```